# Reading in email attachment intereputs 'NA' as blank

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, io, bytesio

I set up a process such that an email attachement gets dropped into S3 and then triggers a Lambda to load into Redshift.

I originally thought Redshift had the problem but turns out, when I read this email attachment as so

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
data = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key_name)
contents = data['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")

# Given the s3 object content is the ses email, get the message content and attachment using email package
msg = email.message_from_string(contents)
attachment = msg.get_payload()[1]
df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(attachment.get_payload(decode=True)),keep_default_na=False,na_values=['NaN'])
```

Gives me this for the region column

```
df['Region'].value_counts()

        56762
EMEA     5092
APAC      480
LA         48
Name: Region, dtype: int64
```

When it should be this when I just read the excel file using `pd.read_excel()`

```
NA      56762
EMEA     5092
APAC      480
LA         48
Name: Region, dtype: int64
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue are greatly appreciated.

How can this be fixed?

My attempt

```
map_dict = {
    '':'NA',
    'EMEA':'EMEA',
    'APAC':'APAC',
    'LA':'LA'
}

df['Region'] = df['Region'].map(map_dict)
```

Is that approach the best? No it looks like a bad idea to me but if anyone knows a better way I am all ears.

Comment: Can you show a minimal Excel spreadsheet that repos this issue?

Comment: @AnonCoward No, because reading in the excel file using pd.read_excel will give the correct results but there is something going on when using the get_payload or io BytesIO